# PHP upload images failure

Tags: php, image, upload, image-uploading

I'm using PHP to create a website for a FileMaker database. What I want to do is upload an image file so it can be accessed by the database.

This is the code I have (which came from a tutorial):

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'Upload') {

    # set the destination directory for the image
    $image_directory = 'http://mydomain.com/Images/My_Example/';

    # set the temp and dest file names with paths
    $temporary_file = $_FILES['new_image']['tmp_name'];
    $destination_file = $image_directory . $_FILES['new_image']['name'];

    # move file to the images directory
    $result = move_uploaded_file($temporary_file, $destination_file);

    if ($result) {

        # insert the URL into the product record
        $edit = $fm->newEditCommand('Product', $_REQUEST['recid']);
        $edit->setField('Thumbnail URL', $destination_file);
        $edit->execute();

    } else {
        $error_message = nl2br("temporary_file = ".$temporary_file."\n");    
        $error_message.= nl2br("destination_file = ".$destination_file."\n\n");    
        echo $error_message;
        die('There was an error moving the file.');
    }
}
```

I understand that the function 'move_uploaded_file()' will move the temporary file, but I can't see a statement that actually uploads to the temporary file in the first place. What am I missing, please? (I don't know if this is a red herring!)

But 'move_uploaded_file()' fails, and I get the error message (which I added to try to debug it) and the 'die' message. Is there any way to get an error code, to tell me *why* it failed?

I'm assured that the relevant directory does have read/write access. And 'mydomain.com' is actually replaced by the real domain in the script.

Any advice gratefully received. I'm a newbie to PHP, so please bear that in mind when answering! Many thanks.

Cheers

Comment: who is the owner of your folder you are trying to upload?

Comment: If that's all you got, I think you're right that the code actually saving the temporary file is missing.

Comment: you don't have to give full path.
your upload path should start from web root

Comment: is the folder is accessible to web

Answer (score 1):

you are using the destination directory path with 'http://mydomain.com/Images/My_Example/', which will not work. 
in order to save the file, you need to give it absolute path on the server - means if the DOCUMENT_ROOT folder is "/var/www/html/", then you'll need to upload it to "/var/www/html/Images/My_Example'. 
you can check your DOCUMENT_ROOT path in the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] variable, with phpinfo() command in php, or in your apache.conf files.
also you need to make sure your php has writing permission on the folder you trying to save into.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not yet sure what DOCUMENT_ROOT is, or where it is! Yes, it definitely has write permission, so I'm told. I'm not doing this on my own computer, but using a FileMaker/PHP host. I don't think I have access to the things you mention. What I see in Cyberduck is everything that comes after the domain name in the browser. Everything above that I don't have access to.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this statement :

```
$image_directory = 'http://mydomain.com/Images/My_Example/';
```

When you upload file, you cannot give the url in the destination path. You need to use the relative path like:

```
$image_directory = './Images/My_Example/';
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the perfect answer to what was wrong! :)

Answer (score 0):

first of all: try these error messages

the error message is in: $_FILES['upfile']['error']

```
    switch ($_FILES['upfile']['error']) {
    case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
        break;
    case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
        throw new RuntimeException('No file sent.');
    case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
    case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
        throw new RuntimeException('Exceeded filesize limit.');
    default:
        throw new RuntimeException('Unknown errors.');
}
```

secondly:  http://mydomain.com/Images/My_Example/ is not a vaild upload path.

Comment: Thanks. Firstly, I've been trying to get hold of a list of the contents of the $_FILES array, but can't find one for love nor money! Thanks for those! Secondly, it would've been useful if you could've said why it wasn't valid. :)

Answer (score 0):

http://mydomain.com/Images/My_Example/  is not valid becuase it is a URL path. You need to specify a directory path:

```
//$image_directory = 'http://mydomain.com/Images/My_Example/';
// change to:
$image_directory = 'path/to/Images/folder/';
```

Comment: Thanks!(8 more to go, it says, what does that mean I wonder?)